# Projective closure of $\mathbb{P}^2\setminus V(x_0x_1x_2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry

I am trying to compute the projective closure of $\mathbb{P}^2\setminus V(x_0x_1x_2)$: the projective space minus the locus of $x_0x_1x_2$ for a problem. But I am stuck. My feeling is that the closure should be the whole projective space $\mathbb P^2$. But all I can think about is that this set can be realized as an affine variety through Veronese embedding $\mathbb{P}^2\hookrightarrow\mathbb P^9 $. But it does not help me see the projective closure of this set. Any hint or thought is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Using ideals: when all ideals are radical, the ideal of the closure of $V(I) \backslash V(J)$ is the quotient $(I : J)$

Comment: Do you mean the closure of $\Bbb P^2\setminus V(x_0x_1x_2)$ as a subset of $\Bbb P^2$? Because that's just $\Bbb P^2$ by irreducibility. If not, what do you mean?

Comment: Closure is a relative notion: you take the closure of *something* in *something else*. For instance, the closure of $(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is $[0,1]$, but the closure of $(0,1)$ in $[0,1)$ is $[0,1)$. For this reason, embedding your open subset in a different space will change what you get for the closure---you have changed the ambient space, the *something else*.

Comment: @Richard D.James Thank you for the clarification, Yeah Veronese embedding will not work here.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to$\textit{ @Oliver Clarke}$'s comment. This is actually pretty simple.

Lemma: When $I$, $J$ are two radical ideal, we know $V(I)\setminus V(J)=
Cl({V(I:J))}.$

Proof: see page 195 in David Cox; John Little; Donal O'Shea (1997). Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms: An Introduction to Computational Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra. Springer.

Here in our case $I=0$. And clearly $V(I:J)=V(0)$ is the whole space.
Of course this coincides with $\textit{@KReiser}$'s comment. Thanks!